# idiomatic way to combine formatting and string appending?

Tags: java, string

Is there a better way to build strings with formatting and appending than this example?    This is a Java question.

Edit: It seems that it would be better if Formatter() was capable of being more like StringBuilder() or that StringBuilder() be capable of being like Formatter().  I especially do not like having to catch an exception given that this is merely a "toString" kind of method, that is to say, trivial.  Also, what if I want to append an integer via %d after the loop?

```
    String methodToYieldMyInstanceAsString()
    {
        Formatter f = new Formatter();
        f.format("%s %d\n", thing1, thing2);

        for (Entry<KeyType, ValueType> entry: map.entrySet())
        {
            try
            {
                f.out().append(entry.getKey().asString() + " ");
                f.out().append(entry.getValue().asString() + "\n");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }
        return f.toString();
    }
```

One good thing about this code is that I only use one Formatter object, for what it's worth.

Comment: If you want to avoid the try/catch block, you can always declare your function as "throws IOException", but it'll have to get caught somewhere.

Comment: Looking for StringBuilder? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: I don't think StringBuilder accepts formats like %d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `IOException` if you call the `format` method yourself, it throws only unchecked exceptions. Just change your code slightly:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Formatter f = new Formatter(builder);

for (...) {
    f.format("%s %d\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

return builder.toString();
```

Comment: This is the best answer because f.format("%f") calls before and after and within the loop all get appended together.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was "How not to have to catch the exception?".

Straight answer:

```
((StringBuilder) f.out()).append(entry.getKey().asString() + " ");
```

Why would that work? Because new Formatter() creates a StringBuilder object as the destination, whereas f.out() returns this destination. The append() method of 
StringBuilder does not declare an exception.

Moreover I don't get, what you're trying to accomplish with that code.
Since you call append() on the destination of the Formatter you're actually
circumventing the Formatter and appending directly to the destination. So the
only use of the Formatter is the call to

```
f.format("%s %d\n", thing1, thing2);
```

Comment: This is a good answer if all you want to do is get rid of the exception catching.  I previously used a cast but changed my mind on the grounds that it was more opaque than the exception handling. Cramming too much stuff on one line.  Exception handling uses a lot of lines but it does not require careful reading.  The point is to use %d kinds of formats and also do appending.  @Tom Jefferys has a good answer although to use more %d formats after the loop I think I would be instantiating more Formatters, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

How about Something like this...

```
String methodToYieldMyInstanceAsString()
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("%s %d\n", thing1, thing2));

    for (Entry<KeyType, ValueType> entry: map.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey().toString();
        String value = entry.getValue().toString();
        sb.append(key).append(value);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your code.  Changed so it does the same thing now.

Answer (score 0):

If `KeyType` and `ValueType` are your own-defined classes, why don't you override `toString()` in those two classes? Then you can simply do

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (Entry<KeyType, ValueType> entry: map.entrySet()) {
  buf.append(entry.getKey().toString())
     .append(entry.getValue().toString())
     .append("\n");
}
return buf.toString();
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to combine formatting with append. There is no %d type of formatting in your example.  The format before the loop is essential to the problem.

Comment: @broiyan: I was suggesting to move the `%d` formatting into the `toString()` method of the `ValueType` class: its the object that should know how to print itself to a string :)